# Input Text into Textfield and Click button on website

Tags: objective-c, networking, web, browser, nsurlconnection

I was wondering if there is any possible way to enter text inside a textfield on a website from an objective-c application, and then click a button. I basically want to put text into a textfield in the centre of a website page, and then click a button, without a web browser being open. If the page changes, I was planning to update the application to say that it was successful.

I was thinking to do something in reverse of downloading something. Could I reverse this code to download an image, so it uploads text into a textfield?

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurl/mypic.jpg"]];
cell.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
[imageData release];
```

There is probably other things involved like using `NSURLConnection` and maybe `NSURLResponse`, which I can use (and have done before, only really simply), but I will need a bit of help if they are involved.

Im really not sure, and are there any search terms I might want to use for googling? The ones I come up with don't seem to return any results.

Thanks in advance!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could just use Javascript to manipulate the website, using a WebView object.

Just get the current scripting object:

```
id currentScriptingObject = [webview windowScriptObject];
```

Then implement javascript commands like this:

```
[currentScriptingObject evaluateWebScript:@"javascript:void(someJavascriptCommand.run);"];
```

Then use `NSString`'s `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello: %@", someString]` for arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this, depending on what the service you're trying to connect to allows:

1. If you're working with a website that has a documented API that you can use to do whatever you're trying to do then use it.  They'll generally have info on how to use it and it's fairly straight-forward.  eBay would be a decent example of this approach.  In many cases it would be simply a matter of creating a NSURLConnection with an appropriately formed NSURL that formats the info needed for the request and will result in a clearly documented response which you would handle in your delegate.
2. If they don't have an API to use if it's a simple GET request you may be able to figure out the format and create your own NSURLConnection as above (eg. http://www.thesiteinquestion.com/here.php?item=4f&quantity=3).
3. If you must manually load the page, fill the form, and submit it you can do it via DOM programming in Obj-C (see https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/WebKitJavaScript.html for more details as it's fairly involved, and see http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/160407-programmatic-web-form-fill-in.html for an example). Fair warning, though: it can be a PITA, and if the form changes in the future your app will likely break.